# How to replace parts of a string and a more. Swift 4

Tags: swift, string, indexing, substring

I have a string:

```
"Location: &lt;&lt;LesionLoc&gt;&gt;<br>
Quality: &lt;&lt;TESTTEST&gt;&gt;<br>"
```

End result should be:

```
Location: &lt;span class=\"span_dropdowntext\" keyword=\"LesionLoc\" style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold;\"contenteditable=\"False\"&gt;LesionLoc&lt;/span&gt;
Quality: &lt;span class=\"span_dropdowntext\" keyword=\"TESTTEST\" style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold;\"contenteditable=\"False\"&gt; TESTTEST&lt;/span&gt;
```

As you can see, all I have to do is:

1. Replace `&lt;&lt;` with `&lt;span class=\"span_dropdowntext\" keyword=\"LesionLoc\" style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold;\"contenteditable=\"False\"&gt;`
2. Replace `&gt;&gt;` with `&lt;/span&gt;`
3. And lastly, (which is what is giving me a hard time), inserting the strings "LesionLoc" and "TESTTEST" into the `keyword=/"/"` part.

Replacing is easy, just use string.replacingOcurences but then I thought it'd be better if I can loop through all the `&lt;&lt;` and `&gt;&gt;`, replace it inside the loop and also insert the strings into the keyword part.

I'm really lost in this. Someone has mentioned using index and substring functions to return the new string, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must find your keyword (in this case is `LesionLoc` and `TESTTEST`). You can find it by using the `NSRegularExpression` with regex format `&lt;&lt;[a-z0-9]+&gt;&gt;`

Next, replace your `&lt;&lt;` with

```
&lt;span class=\"span_dropdowntext\" keyword=\"<KEYWORD>\"style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold;\"contenteditable=\"False\"&gt;
```

and `&gt;&gt;` with `&lt;/span&gt;`.

You can using this very simple code

```
var string = "Location: &lt;&lt;LesionLoc&gt;&gt;<br>\nQuality: &lt;&lt;TESTTEST&gt;&gt;<br>"

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "&lt;&lt;[a-z0-9]+&gt;&gt;", options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
    for text in regex.matches(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count)).reversed() {
        let keyword = (string as NSString).substring(with: text.range).replacingOccurrences(of: "&lt;&lt;", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "&gt;&gt;", with: "")
        let newString = "&lt;span class=\"span_dropdowntext\" keyword=\"\(keyword)\" style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold;\"contenteditable=\"False\"&gt;\(keyword)&lt;/span&gt;"
        string = (string as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: text.range, with: newString)
    }
    print(string)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private func replaceString(_ str : String)->String{
    guard let keyword = findKeyword(str) else{
        fatalError()
    }
    let replacementString = "&lt;span class=\"span_dropdowntext\" keyword=\"\(keyword)\" style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold;\"contenteditable=\"False\"&gt;"

    var newString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "&gt;&gt", with: "&lt;/span&gt")
    newString = newString.replacingOccurrences(of: "&lt;&lt;", with: replacementString)
    return newString
}

private func findKeyword(_ s : String)->String?{
    var str = Array(s)
    let firstKey = "&lt;&lt;"
    let secondKey = "&gt;&gt"

    var startingIndex : Int = 0
    var movingIndex : Int = 0

    while  movingIndex < str.count + 1 - secondKey.count && startingIndex < str.count + 1 - firstKey.count{
        if String(str[startingIndex..<startingIndex + firstKey.count]) != firstKey{
            startingIndex += 1
        }else{
            if movingIndex < startingIndex + firstKey.count{
                movingIndex = startingIndex + firstKey.count
            }else{
                if String(str[movingIndex..<movingIndex + secondKey.count]) != secondKey{
                    movingIndex += 1
                }else{
                    return String(str[startingIndex+firstKey.count..<movingIndex])
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Now, you can use the replaceString function to do the work

```
let string = "Location: &lt;&lt;LesionLoc&gt;&gt;<br>"
print(replaceString(string))
```

your end result will be

```
Location: &lt;span class="span_dropdowntext" keyword="LesionLoc" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;"contenteditable="False"&gt;LesionLoc&lt;/span&gt;<br>
```

There is a "br" at the end of the result string. I don't know if you wanna to remove that or not.. But if you do, you should know how to .